# In TI-BASIC, how do I display the Variable Name given only the variable?

Tags: ti-basic, ti-nspire

I'm creating a function that displays a lot of variables with the format Variable + Variable Name.

```
Define LibPub out(list)=
Func
Local X
for x,1,dim(list)
  list[x]->name // How can I get the variable name here?
  Disp name+list[x]
EndFor
Return 1
EndFunc
```

Answer (score 1):

Given a list value, there is no way to find its name.

Consider this example:

```
a:={1,2,3,4}
b:=a               ; this stores {1,2,3,4} in b
out(b)
```

**Line 1:** First the value `{1,2,3,4}` is created. Then an variable with name `a` is created and its value is set to `{1,2,3,4}`.

**Line 2:** The expression `a` is evaluated; the result is `{1,2,3,4}`. A new variable with the name `b` is created and its value is set to `{1,2,3,4}.

**Line 3:** The expression `b` is evaluated. The variable reference looks up what value is stored in `b`. The result is `{1,2,3,4}`. This value is then passed to the function `out`.

The function `out` receives the value `{1,2,3,4}`. Given the value, there is no way of knowing whether the value happened to be stored in a variable. Here the value is stored in both `a` and `b`.

However we can also look  at `out({1,1,1,1}+{0,2,3,4})`.

The system will evaluate `{1,1,1,1}+{0,2,3,4}` and get `{1,2,3,4}`. Then `out` is called. The value `out` received the result of an expression, but an equivalent value happens to be stored in `a` and `b`. This means that the values doesn't have a name.

In general: Variables have a name and a value. Values don't have names.

If you need to print a name, then look into strings.

Answer (score 0):

This will be memory intensive, but you could keep a string of variable names, and separate each name by some number of characters and get a substring based on the index of the variable in the list that you want to get. For instance, say you want to access index zero, then you take a substring starting at (index of variable * length of variable name, indexofvariable *length + length+1).
The string will be like this: say you had the variables foo, bas, random, impetus
the string will be stored like so: "foo     bas        random  impetus "